# How to use document_html with pdflayer properly when using js / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, asp.net-mvc-4, layer

I am trying to use pdflayer api to create pdf files. I was able to use document_url but need to use document_html to get desired output. I am using ajax post to send a request but get failure everytime where it says document source not provided. I have tried different variations of the following code to get it to accept. Tried passing the access key down below but it doesn't recognizes it as it doesn't any of my other parameters:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://api.pdflayer.com/api/convert?access_key=***",
            formData: {
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                document_html: html,
                page_size: 'A4',
                test: 1,
                encoding: null,
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
```

Another alternative that is **not** working:

```
var html = $('.pdfcontainer').html();
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("access_key", "***");
        data.append("document_html", html);
        data.append("page_size", "A4");
        data.append("test", 1);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://api.pdflayer.com/api/convert",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
```

The output log shows:

when I put access key in query string ->

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "code": 313,
        "type": "missing_document_source",
        "info": "You have not specified a document source. Please use either document_url or document_html."
    }
}
```

If access key is not in query string ->

```
{
    "code": 101,
    "type": "missing_access_key",
    "info": "You have not supplied an API Access Key. [Required format: access_key=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY]"
}
```

I tried using the formData, I tried passing values without that, I tried putting just the html within and everything else outside, I tried putting everything in query string and just the html in form, nothing works.

Comment: Sorry about the two tags: pdf and layer. Apparently I needed 1500 reps to use the tag pdflayer as it would have been termed a new tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to send a request via Postman setting the `document_html` parameter on the body as form-data:
[image: screenshot]

Hopefully this helps.